# How to delete a Frame in the UFT Object Repository

Tags: qtp

I'm using the Object Repository to record objects in an application so someone else can use them to automate some test scripts. Most of the objects follow a hierarchy of Browser -> Page -> Object, but some of them go Browser -> Page -> Frame -> Object. The other tester has asked me to delete the frame, but retain the child objects. They said this works fine on their install, but on mine deleting the frame takes all of the child objects with it. Any ideas on how to remove the frame from the hierarchy while preserving everything else?

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy all your child objects of a frame.
2. Paste them under your page object directly.
3. Now you can delete the frame object and its child.
4. You have to update your code accordingly, 
   Example-

> `Browser("Browser1").Page("Page1").Frame("Frame1").Link("YourLink").Click`

to

> ```
> Browser("Browser1").Page("Page1").Link("YourLink").Click
> ```

Comment: I tried this and rather than copying the items under the page, it creates a new page and copies both the items AND the frame. For example, PageName_1 contains Frame_1 which in turn contains Objects X, Y, and Z. If I copy Objects X, Y, and Z, then paste them under PageName_1, UFT creates PageName_2, which contains, Frame_1, which then contains the copies of X, Y, and Z.

Comment: OR is nothing but XML file stored on file system. What you can do is find a file and do the modification. See link here - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_or_as_xml.htm